# What options do I have to sign in in big commerce?

Tags: shopify, bigcommerce

I'm researching in behalf of my company to implement shopify or big commerce to support our store while we still use our admin and cloud services for the rest.

Shopify offer Multipass to allow a web to redirect to the store and keep the user logged plus API and webhooks which could allow me to user's created in the store be reflected in our cloud DB.

But I can't find nothing remotely similar in Big Commerce. Am I right and Big Commerce doesn't any mechanism to integrate existing services with their stores?

Comment: They are a for-profit company, ask them what their product can do... https://www.bigcommerce.co.uk/contact/

Comment: [bigcommerce api integration](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/)

Comment: Big Commerce ask to create a ticket here, my dear friends, so if you don't have a constructive answer don't even try

Answer (score 0):

BigCommerce offers three methods for accessing store data and functionality:

1. The web interface - This is your standard browser based control panel, where you would view data and perform functions using their UI.
2. [The Stores API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/) - You can develop an application (or connect an existing service using a plugin) to connect to the API using Basic Authentication or OAuth. This method could be used to poll for new users and replicate them in your remote database.
3. [Webhooks](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started) - You can subscribe to events (like customer create or update) and parse the response object to replicate the object on your remote database.